# qemu-kvm crash "End of file from qemu monitor"

Tags: centos7, qemu, kvm

I created a kvm domain,but it always crash after running about a day.

Here are some error messages in libvirtd.log:

```
2020-08-13 13:46:15.906+0000: 2018: error : qemuMonitorIO:718 : internal error：End of file from qemu monitor
2020-08-13 13:46:15.906+0000: 2018: debug : qemuMonitorIO:765 : Error on monitor internal error：End of file from qemu monitor
```

and some error messages in the domain's log:

```
qemu: qemu_thread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I have checked the free ram is enough

Run ulimit -a:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 385903
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 204800
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 1024
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 204800
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This community is dedicated to software development while you question appears to be related to sysadmin's tasks and therefore is off-topic here. There is a chance that some guys here COULD help you but I doubt anyone will even try because your question will get deleted anyway soon. You will have better chances for the answer either at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServelFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)